# Outlook 2010 stopped search service

Tags: microsoft-outlook

After Microsoft update, email search is not working in Outlook. I tried with System Restore, Uninstall office updates and Index rebuild. This fixed in some PCs, but still the issue exist in some PC even after doing the same. Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to uninstall the security updates if it is what you uninstalled.

There is a known issue about Outlook search after June security update, it is fixed now. Please check the issue #5 in below article:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Outlook-known-issues-in-the-June-2017-security-updates-3f6dbffd-8505-492d-b19f-b3b89369ed9b

STATUS: FIXED
Windows has released fixes via Windows Updates to address a reliability issue in Windows Search. Below are the relevant KB updates for each version:

Windows 7 -  KB4022168

Windows 8.1 -  KB4022720

Windows 10 Version 1703 -  KB4022716

Windows 10 Version 1607 -  KB4022723

Windows 10 Version 1511 -  KB4032673

Windows 10 -  KB4032695

NOTE: The fix for this issue has been released on June 27, 2017. If you implemented the workaround, you can now set the PreventIndexingOutlook registry key to DWORD: 0 to go back to using Windows Search.

Comment: Can you add the relevant information from the link to this answer? As it currently stands, this is a link-only answer.

Comment: Updated. Thank you @music2myear for the kind suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Run the MS Outlook Inbox Repair tool `scanpst.exe` against the Outlook datafile.

It can be found in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14 or C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14 depending on your system architecture.

After running the tool you will need to rebuild your search index.

I have used the repair tool in the past and it did fix the search functionality.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to added an instruction for how to rebuild the index for other readers who find your answer.  :-)